# How to implement Single Date and Time Picker in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, datepicker, timepicker

Reference to Magento documentation, I want to implement "Single Date and Time Picker" mentioned in [Devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/pattern-library/getting-user-input/date_time_selector/date_time_selector.html).

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution as like screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="datepicker" id="datepicker" title="datepicker" value="" type="text">
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/calendar"
    ], function($){
        $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
                stepMinute: 15,
                minDate: new Date(),
                dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
                beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                hourMin: 6,
                hourMax: 16
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good reference with all available settings:
https://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento2-show-calendar-date-picker-field-in-custom-form/